# Validation in jQuery and redirect new page with error fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

How to validate my all fields by using jquery ?

if validation fails,i want to redirect to new page and list out all validation failed fields.If it is success i will do insert operation.

```
Example

<input class="textbox validate"type="text"> 

<input class="textbox validate"type="text"> 


//validate the all the field with having "validate" class
$(".validate").each
```

I am using MVC-3 but i want to do in custom j-query logic. I am a new person in j-query.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Looks like you on the right track. Add a function for your .each to call that checks the validation and if that fails do your browser redirect

Comment: Thanks Scott, I will try with my one and get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a single function for validation:

```
function validate (text) {
  ...
  return true; //or false
}
```

Then one thing you can do:

```
var validationErrors = [],
    errorPageURL = "BASE URL for your error page";

$(".validate").each(function (index, element) { 

  if (!validate(element.val()) {
    validationErrors.push($(element).id);
  }
});

if (validationErrors.length === 0) {
  //Do your input magic
} else {
  window.location.replace(errorPageURL + "?errors=" + encodeURI(JSON.stringify(validationErrors)));
}
```

A few reference links:

- [jQuery val method](http://api.jquery.com/val/)
- [jQuery each method](http://api.jquery.com/each/)
- [About client-side redirects (with/without jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

Comment: Thanks mlr, I will try with yours and get back to you

Comment: This looks good. Sometimes I like to also push back the error as a jquery object and not just an id so I can add visual cues to the error like adding a red border around something without using another call that looks up the element to do something.